# Call python Multivariate linear regression code from C++ Application

Tags: python, c++

I am doing my research in networking and I want to implement linear regression on my own data set(numeric). I used `python` for multivariate linear regression using `sklearn` library  and now I want to embed/call that `python` implementation from my `c++` code.

AS if I say that `c++` is my application and python code is a service which provides services to my `c++` code....
and I need pyhton code output in `c++` code so I want to call python executable in `c++`.

can I do that?

I search a lot as boost one is but I am not understanding how can I do... I used `jupyter notebook` for `python` and eclipse for c++.

```
x = final_tf[['LocalLoadHigh', 'LocalLoadLow', 'TransitLoadHigh',
    'TransitLoadLow','phaseTotalBlocking', 'phaseTotalLocalBlocking', 'phaseTotalTransitBlocking', 'PBlockingLocalHigh',
    'PBlockingLocalLow', 'PBlockingTransitHigh', 'PBlockingTransitLow',
    'UtilizationHigh', 'UtilizationLow']]
                # Create target variable, y

y = final_tf['WavelengthGroup']
 # Import model
 # Create linear regression object
lm = LinearRegression()
print(np.isfinite(x).all())
model = lm.fit(x,y)
predictions = lm.predict(x)
print(predictions)
lm.score(x,y)
lm.coef_
```

Comment: You have two ways: Either you call Python as second executable from your C++ code or you embed a Python interpreter into your C++ program. Both ways are possible, just do a bit of research on them and you will find sufficient documentation. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: An approach to reduce the complexity of the problem you're facing would be to just do your regression in C++.

Comment: i am searching code to apply multivariate linear regression in c++....but also not finding some good solution...if you have some suggestion can tell me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want different languages to collaborate, you have 2 possible ways.

1. the easy way: external program and communication through pipes/files:

   - you prepare the input data in your C++ program and save it to a file
   - you launch a python interpretor to execute your python script with fork/exec (on Linux), spawn (on Windows) or simply with `system` ; the python script reads the input file, apply the regression tools and save the results to an output file
   - you read the output file from your C++ application
   - alternatively, you could use pipes instead of plain files
2. the hard way: embed a Python interpretor in your C++ program and use the Python API or a tool like swift or sip to manage the passing of data from one language to the other.

   This will certainly be more efficient (less overhead of launching processes and serializing data) but the way to embed Python as a dynamic library depends on the actual OS. Refer to the Python documentation for your system.

Comment: i think 1st way is good.... and is there any link if you can provide... i am not findling the good one... i am very thankful if you solve my problem... i am not good in coding... i just try to code... so please you can provide some code reference for the 1st step

Comment: This is not the recommended way in production code for security reasons, but something like `system("/path/to/python /path/to/script.py script_params...");` is simple to use for tests.

Comment: hii....i tried this by using this linkhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/66923708/embedding-python-function-in-c....but getting issue that when i run the program in the link it executes but when i change it then it is not importing ...please can you tell is there library issue